# Colon doesn't exist where it does in pycharm

Tags: python

```py
var = input()
if var = ("lookup"):
    print(input())
    var = 0
```

It says I need a ":" on the second line but there is already one there. What do I do?

Comment: Please, **do not post images of code**. Post **all code as formatted text**.

Comment: The problem here is you are using `=` instead of `==`

Comment: You need to use the boolean operator `==` instead of the assignment operator `=`

Comment: think it probably says `:=` as you are missing a second `=` operator! Your not comparing, your setting

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga **Please do not answer in comments**

Comment: @EkadhSingh I voted to close that's why I pointed out the typo

Comment: Please don't vandalise your question, it will just get rolled back.

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure what your problem is, but this is some code that runs:

```py
var = input()
if var == "lookup":
    print(input())  # printing what is input?
    var = 0
```

You were checking if var is "lookup", but as pointed out in the comments, you were missing an "=" sign. Please edit your post to explain exatcly what is needed (post input / output examples).

Answer (score 1):

To compare var you need to use the double equal symbol (==) instead of the single equal symbol (=). The single equal symbol is used for assignment as you did in the first line (var = input('Enter a string: ')).

```
var = input('Enter a string: ')
if var == "lookup":
    print(input('Enter the second string: ')) # input the value then it prints the same
    var = 0
print(v"now var is: {var}")
```

Output:

```
Enter a string: lookup
Enter the second string: Demo
Demo
now var is: 0
```